# Magento, Upgrade 1.7 query failed in custom module with sales_flat_quote_item_option table

Tags: magento

I have written a custom module in Magento who add a row in the sales_flat_quote_item_option table.
I use the addOption method with an array as parameter on a quote_item object.
Then I run $quoteItem->save();

With version 1.4 of Magento, everything works like a charm. I tried to upgrade Magento to 1.7 version but my module seems to not working anymore.

After couple try to debug, I figure that the insert query in sales_flat_quote_item_option is not launch at all (according to the query log file).

So I wrote a simple query to insert data and my module is working now.

Maybe someone has been already facing this kind of issue ? I need to do it as clean as possible.

Let me share the code who fails :

```
public function assignDocumentToQuoteItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $quoteItem, $documentid)
    {

        if(is_numeric($documentid) && $documentid > 0)
        {
            /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
            $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();

            $quoteItem->addOption(array(
                        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                        'product' => $product,
                        'code' => 'documentid',
                        'value' => $documentid));
            $quoteItem->save();
            return true;
        }

        throw new Exception(__METHOD__.' - Document id has to be a numeric value.');

    }
```

Works fine with Magento 1.4 but not with 1.7 any idea here ?

Thank you very much !